# One Hot Encoder con columna ID que no debe ser tocada ni modificada, ¿cómo proceder en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una tabla que posee varias columnas: ID, Género, Región, Nivel Educacional, Edad, Comuna, y otras 25 más, y más de 100 mil registros, que a continuación comparto con una imagen de ejemplo (no puedo colocar todas las columnas porque poseen datos sensibles)...

[image: Muestra de datos del archivo CSV]

Por lo tanto a la tabla debo hacer un "One Hot Encoder" a gran parte de las variables Objetos y Categóricos y a unas numéricas, pero a la columna 'ID' y a otras, como por ejemplo 'Edad', no se le debe aplicar el proceso, **con el fin de poder crear un único archivo CSV** con todas las columnas no transformadas y con las columnas resultantes del "One Hot Encoder" reemplacen a las columnas originales a las cuales se le aplicó.

Sé que se puede hacer con **pandas.get_dummies** pero no logro que todo quede en un mismo dataframe para luego guardar en un CSV nuevo.
Logro el One Hot Encoder con pandas, pero creando otro dataframe aparte con la instrucción...

`cat_org = pd.get_dummies(dataframe[columns], drop_first = True, dummy_na = True)`

donde 'columns' contiene las columnas que interesa aplicar el One Hot Encoder, pero no posee la columna 'ID' y temo que si junto con otra, se mezclen los datos y el resultado sea inservible.
Puede que esté perdido o ahogándome en un baso de agua, pero no logro lo que requiero.

Se agradece muchísimo la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casi lo tienes! Tan solo hay que pasar el DataFrame entero a `get_dummies` y las columnas que quiere en one-hot.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', 'y', 'x'], 'B': ['z', 'u', 'z'],
                  'C': ['1', '2', '3'],
                  'D':['j', 'l', 'j']})

pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['A', 'B', 'D'])
```

### Update

Como puedes ver la columna **C** en este caso podría ser tu **ID** y está manteniendo los número igual, después de la operación

Comment: ¿Y ello no hace que, por ejemplo, la fila 15 del one hot encoder sea la fila 25 en el resultado final? Ese eso es a lo que no tengo claro. ¿Se mantiene el orden original? y luego al llevarlo a una nueva tabla en donde se reúne con el resto de datos, ¿se mantiene integro los datos para cada ID (me refiero en el orden)?

Comment: Sí, claro las filas se mantienen en el mismo orden! Es decir todos los datos tienen el ID correspondiente que tenían inicialmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclararme la duda @rubialesalberto funcionó perfecto.

Comment: De nada! Me alegro.